# not able to launch nunit test from visual c# express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I am using visual c# express 2010 and trying to run a simple unit test using nunit. I have added a reference for the nunit dll and also added it to external tools.

But when I click on Nunit on the tools menu, I get this error(please click on link to get a screen shot of the error):

http://lab.v2techlabs.com/nunit_error.png

Apparently some dll is not found. I am new to c# unit tests so can someone point me in right direction? I am using nunit 2.6

Comment: I guess, the missing dll is the compilation result of your (Class Library) project. Did you compile it before running NUnit? Also verify that the path to the dll exists.

Comment: Yes the dll was missing. I figured it out after some time. Thanks.